# Is it possible to call the original (unwrapped) setInterval function in PhoneGap?

Tags: javascript, cordova

PhoneGap wraps the `setInterval` function, so that console.log returns this:

```
function wrapped_setInterval(code, interval)
    var id = Native.setInterval(code, interval)   
    code.__timerId = id
    addTimer(id, interval, false)
    return id
}
```

How can I call the original `setTimeout` function? It seems to be backed up in `Native.original.setTimeout`, is there a way to get access to the `Native` object?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? You'd only subvert whatever PhoneGap is doing to keep track of the timer. The whole point is that `Native.setInterval` does not have the complete functionality of `setInterval`, and that's why it's wrapped in some supplementary JS.

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin I'm running into a problem where, when the date changes while the app is running, setInterval stops working. I eval'd a simple setInterval, and it works when the app starts but not after the date change. I'm trying to find out if it works if I use the original `setInterval`.